# How is a Authentication and Authorisation service implemented for an ESB

Tags: authentication, authorization, single-sign-on, esb, saml

I am working on a security component to use with an ESB for a client with very concrete high level requirements:

1. Integrate into an existing IWay service manager version 5.5 ESB (there is no security system in the existing set up).
2. Provide authentication and authorisation level information from source data stored in an existing active directory server used for another system (preferably using LDAP).
3. Authentication and authorisation should be performed in the ESB as the interface for the ESB will be exposed to both internal and external clients so total control over the client is not possible.
4. The client can not be relied up to have a certificate to allow bilateral SSL authentication, however unilateral authentication, where the client checks to see he is hitting the correct server is possible, so HTTPS connections can be established.
5. The service should sit on Weblogic (but I will be happy to take suggestions regardless)

Further information:
IWay ESB is a commercial, closed and fairly poor solution, in version 5.5 it provides no out of the box solution which fits the requirements. it is also stateless so no sessions can be maintained other than using a cookie or some method similar to store information.

Current ideas:
To implement a SSO service that is added to the messaging bus which provides a identity provider, service provider functionality, so an initial authentication will provide a token, which can then be stored by the client and passed with each subsequent request to be authenticated and an authorisation level passed (which i believe to be a fairly standard design pattern).

Research has been carried out on SSO + SAML implementation, openAM, Shibboleth, CAS all seem to provide a too complete solution which caters more for a portal type architecture (like CAS)  or from a system where the initial SAML identity token is received from another sever altogether and then brought to the system (like googles implementation of SAML for some of its services).

I have also looked into JBossESB, openESB and service mix solutions which seem to use a bespoke implementation of SAML which can't be ported onto Weblogic and Zxid which has limited documentation.

It is a complex undertaking so I am expecting more high level architectural styles and library/project suggestions rather than complete solutions. I am under the impression that this should be a reasonably common requirement, a authentication and authorisation service for a ESB which uses a token system to prevent credentials having to be continually entered or stored in plain text but I am unable to find much information, what am I missing?

Any further questions I would be more than happy to elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a solution using SAML is a valid solution for when users potentially/do require to access a third party service on an ESB but don't want the third party service to be aware of the security specifics of the ESB and the credentials information of the user. This way the ESB may provide a SAML token provider where the user can get the ticket and transport it to different services for authentication, the services then check back with the token for authentication and possible authorisation information (with SAML2 only). In addition to this SAML could be used like open ID where users are managed externally and users go to the external token provider to get SAML tickets.

This was a valid solution for us as the the client wanted to be very aware of the users accessing the ESB and there was to be no plan to access third party services as it was a completely closed system.

We subsequently implemented a more custom SAAS (security as a service) mechanism for internal authentication and authorisation inside the ESB (I know it sounds bad but with iWay there are limited options) using spring security libraries and the remember me functionality which in our case met the requirements.

Low and behold our clients then changed their requirements and asked for integration with share point. This did however simplify the security model in our system because we then designed of the following:

iWay's primary security model is based around SSL certificates, it is possible to implement an SSL Provider which will manage certificates, you should therefore be able to supply share point with your SSL certificate and iWay with the public certificate and secure up the channels between the 2 servers, you can then manage users within iWay who can access the ESB on a system level and specify a share point user even specifying it's ip, this information is sent in plain text but over SSL and in our case sent between servers in the same network.

We are then leaving it to share point to authenticate users on a finer level so access to applications is managed at the share point 'portal' level and the only thing the ESB is vaguely aware of is the authorisation information which is passed with the client SOAP message and defines to what level the services can be accessed (this information is used on a service level).

Downsides to this solution are:

For each new client application developed to access the ESB interfaces a new ESB user must be configured so it is not possible for clients to be developed which can freely consume certain services on the ESB.

New clients have to implement the authorisation logic so the correctly formated authorisation string can be sent and understood by services.

Other points:

I am aware that the newer version of iWay provides a LDAP adaptor which should be able to communicate with AD so you can have your LDAP server attached to the ESB through this way so it could possibly be consumed by another client or services in the ESB but you would have to customise share point to access the information through the iWay business provider.

I also believe iWay 6 provides a SAML token provider which you could utilize (going back to what I said previous about the use of SAML) but I don't believe this fits in with a share point solution.

I would like to share more ideas seen as we are both doing the same thing, can you find me through my twitter account which is specified in my blog?

Answer (score 0):

We are currently working with iWay Server Manager 6.0.1 and are also having difficulties identifying HOW to handle security for web services within this tool.

We want to build web services with it that have AD security in them like if we were using .NET Web Services and haven't found a solution.  Even discussing this with the iWay staff did not clear it in our minds.

Now we have to connect to SharePoint web services and the issue will definitely be there.

Have you progressed with your situation?  We would like some feedback from people using the tool on how they actually implement security with iWay.

Comment: Can't fit answer to your question in comment box so put beneath my answer to my question (below)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay... been quite busy over here...

Basically we've done many tests between iWay and SharePoint and we are not able to set it up to sent the NTLM credentials required by SharePoint.  We've tried setting up channels, proxies and various other solutions within the tool...

We've placed a call to them to hopefully get some help...

Pascal

Comment: Is it possible for you to contact me through twitter or email (in my profile), I would like to discuss this further as I think we could help each other but don't think this is the correct platform for this sort of communication.